# -нн- в суффиксах страдательных причастий прошедшего времени

Tags: причастия

Какое из условий написания двух -н- в страдательных причастиях прошедшего времени подходит для слова обещанный. Спасибо

Comment: В сети нашла объяснение, что данное причастие образовано от глагола совершенного вида, но ведь обещать - глагол несовершенного вида.

Comment: Совершенного и несовершенного вида!

Comment: Это двувидовой глагол: и совершенного и несовершенного. ОБЕЩАТЬ, -аю, -аешь; обещанный; -щан, -а, -о. ***св. и нсв***. См. Толковый словарь Кузнецова.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Два н (нн) пишется в бесприставочных причастиях, образованных от глаголов совершенного вида. Сюда также относятся двувидовые глаголы(имеющие значение и совершенного, и несовершенного вида). Слово ***"обещанный"*** относится к двувидовому глаголу.

Comment: Серж, а почему  двувидовой глагол  "ранить имеет две формы: раненный (прич.) и раненый (прил.)?

Comment: Вера, а при чем тут раненый/раненный? Речь идет о глаголе "обещать''.

Comment: Вы приводите правило, согласно которому  в глагольных формах, образованных от двувидовых глаголов,  пишутся две буквы НН.

Comment: Я привожу правило, которое взято из академического справочника.

Comment: Пишутся также с нн причастия не на -ованный (-ёванный, -еванный) глаголов совершенного вида и соотносительные с ними прилагательные; подавляющее большинство таких глаголов содержит приставку.По этому правилу пишутся и формы двувидовых (имеющих значение и совершенного, и несовершенного вида) глаголов венчать, завещать, обещать, казнить, родить: венчанный, завещанный, обещанный, казнённый, рождённый.

Comment: Глагол ***ранить*** относится к правилу о причастий не на ованный(-ёванный, -еванный) глаголов несовершенного вида (которые образуются только от бесприставочных глаголов) и соотносительных с ними прилагательных, пишущихся по-разному: причастия с нн, прилагательные — с одним н.

Comment: Значит, на всегда двувидовой глагол образует причастия с НН, специальный список имеется? По крайней мере, глагол ранить туда не входит.

Comment: В списке пару глаголов.

Comment: контузить, крестить и ранить. В первом правиле эти глаголы оговариваются.

Comment: Да, Серж, как-то всё сложно получается, думаю, должно быть более простое и убедительное решение, чем словарные списки без обоснований.

Comment: У Розенталя этот пункт вообще отсутствует.

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1). Это полная форма страдательного причастия.

2). Причастие "обещанный" образовано от глагола "обещать" - основа на -ать.

3). "Обещать" - переходный глагол (несовершенного вида).

Больше никаких условий, препятствующих или способствующих написанию двух -н- в суффиксе.

Comment: Галина, "обещать" двувидовой глагол.

Comment: Куп***ить*** купленный.